# How to change the same values everywhere - in service , controllers, outside angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

service implementation

```
myService = function()
{
    this.config = {
        show0: false,
        show1: true,
        role : -1,
        id : -1; 
    };
};
```

---

in controller, I map the config values

```
$scope.config = myService.config; //I guess this by reference, isnt it???
```

in templates of these controllers for e.g. the $scope.config.show0 is used with for e.g. ng-model

---

Now outside angular in my threejs code

I get the service using injector which I have defined earlier and change some values depending on certain conditions

```
var service = window.my.injector.get('myService');
service.config.id = 1991;
```

---

Now this value is not immediately reflected in the HTMl template,

`Source = {{config.id}}` still renders as `Source =  -1`

But when I click on some other button in the same template which is mapped to any other value in the same scope

`Source = {{config.id}}` still renders as `1991`

---

How should I force this rerendering or refreshing in my non angular code soon after

```
var service = window.my.injector.get('myService');
service.config.id = 1991;
///do something to refresh that controller
```

---

**Am I using the service wrong? How should I make this config available in angular controllers, templates and non angular code if not via a service?**

Shouldnt changing the $scope.config properties values and changing the values outside angular by retrieving the service via injector change the values everywhere ?

Comment: sorry to bother you but what's window.my ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the angular digest cycle does not kick in from your threejs code. I am not sure where your three js code is, but try using $scope.$apply to kick in the digest cycle, and it should work fine.

If you can share a jsFiddle, I can have a better understanding on what you are trying to achieve, but the reason why this is not happening is, as I said, that the digest cycle does not kick in.